# Mutiple SetTimeout not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, settimeout

I use the following script to play 2 sound files after a timedelay

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function playSound(soundfile,soundfile1) 
    {
        document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML= "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"true\" />";
        setTimeout(function(){document.write ('<EMBED src= "' + soundfile1 + '" hidden=true    autostart=true loop=false>')},2000);
        setTimeout(function(){alert("You have successfully launched the MedOrient website! \n Thank you for launching Sri sai medical jobs.");},3000);
        setTimeout("window.location='http://url'",8000);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="playSound('clapping.mp3','fireworks56.mp3');"  ><img  src="ribbon-cutting.jpg"/></a> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is working in Chrome, but is not working in firefox or IE.
The soundfile1(fireworks56.mp3) plays after few(approx. 8) seconds, but it does not redirect.
In the firefox status bar it shows,

```
  Read http://url
```

Comment: **Never use document.write after the document has loaded.**

If you don't have to support older versions of IE, look into using an HTML5 audio element.

Comment: I used `document.write` purposefully to show a blank page while playing the media and redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `document.write` that will overwrite the page with new content.

Try below code, I changed `document.write` and assigned the value to  `document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML`

```
function playSound(soundfile,soundfile1) 
  {
    document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML= "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"true\" />";
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML= '<EMBED src= "' + soundfile1 + '" hidden=true    autostart=true loop=false>'},2000);
    setTimeout(function(){alert("You have successfully launched the MedOrient website! \n Thank you for launching Sri sai medical jobs.");},3000);
    setTimeout("window.location='http://url'",8000);
  }
```

Comment: still it's not working in firefox and IE8. Can You Please look at my site [link](http://medorient.com/open.html)

Comment: Check here, http://jsfiddle.net/q7VtE/2/. Click on the link, you should see a alert and after 8 seconds page will be redirected.

Comment: Now the pop-up and redirect works, still the sound is not working! help me

Comment: Check mp3 file path is correct. Try using `audio` tag for playing audio's.

Comment: As, I mentioned in my post, in Google chrome the audio is working, that means that the audio path is correct, can u explain me how to use audio tag in the script i used above.